# Rails - Globalize and Permanent_record dependent: :destroy callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soft-delete, globalize

In a Rails 4.2 project I use `gem 'permanent_records'` to handle records soft-deletion and `gem 'globalize'` for translations.

Globalize sets the following relationships between the translated Model and the Translation Model ([source](https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/master/lib/globalize/active_record/act_macro.rb#L100)):

```
has_many :translations, :class_name  => translation_class.name,
                                :foreign_key => options[:foreign_key],
                                :dependent   => :destroy,
                                :extend      => HasManyExtensions,
                                :autosave    => true,
                                :inverse_of  => :globalized_model
```

The result is that calling `:destroy` on the translated Model, does not delete it (which is what permanent_records is used for), but I lose the related translations, which I'd like to keep *alive*.

Shall I override the `dependent: :destroy` callback only on some translated models (the translated models where I use permanent_records)? How to do it properly?

Is there any other way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by adding a `deleted_at` attribute to `GlobalizedModel::Translation` Model (in my case `Treatment::Translation`) so that also translations are soft-deleted.

Answer (score 2):

There many ways to handle it. I wouldn't recommend to override dependent: :destroy.

1. best way to handle it by using paranoia gem which is a re-implementation of acts_as_paranoid. This gem takes care of soft delete with dependent destroy option.
   Refer: https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia
2. Override callback like this

   ```
   def destroy
     run_callbacks :destroy do
       # your code here for destroy
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you input. Unfortunately I can't change the used gems. Anyway, as far I see in Paranoia doc, it relies on the dependent: :destroy associations defined in the models. My problem is that those associations are defined by Globalize itself for translated models, so I can really play with it...

Comment: Try the second option then